# Understanding RaspberryPi Images

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, filesystems

I recently made my first experience with Raspberry Pi. After some while I accidentally deleted an important file, and so I was told to install the image from another Pi. So I was taking out the SD card from the working one and created an image with "Disc-Imager". After putting back this image onto my own SD card, I was wondering about the files I could see in my Windows Explorer. I cannot remember what Files there had been (I'm already at home now) , but anyway - how can it be that after installing the image I can see some Files under Windows? I know of course that the file systems are different, but how are the files which I see under Windows related to the file contents under Linux? Because of different file systems I would expect, that the freshly prepared SD card cannot be read from Windows at all. So what did I see here?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first partition is FAT and is therefore readable on Windows. Take a look [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained) where they explain NOOBS partitioning.

Comment: it means that I see only files required for the boot process. All other structures are invisible?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to see them on Windows because windows does not understand the file system used there by default. You would have to install an extension that will make Windows recognize this filesystem or use a Linux machine to mount this partition.